# "My scarf falls off on you." Can "on" go after "fall off"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

> My scarf falls off on you.

Does the sentence make sense when we use **"falls off on"**?
Could **"on" go after "fall off"?**

Or, can we **avoid the "on" totally** and still have a sentence that makes sense? like:

> My scarf falls off you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *to fall off* + a prepositional phrase (in this case the preposition is *on)*

To your example:

> My scarf fall off on you.

With a singular subject it needs to be *falls off on*.

In your example, it seems like you referring to a past occurrence, so I would use:

> My scarf **fell off** on you.

A more sensible use of *falls off on* might be:

> If my ring is too loose it **falls off** on the table.

In your second example, it is different when you write:

> My scarf **fell off** you.

You substituted the prepositional phrase *on you* with a direct object (you), so the meaning changes.

This phrase is saying that "you" had the scarf on, and it fell off. But it does not say where it went.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don't have the rep on this site to comment. I am trying to visualize the situation.  Who is wearing the scarf?  If the speaker is wearing the scarf, is she bending over the other person?  If so, say: "My scarf fell on you", or, if it is happening as you speak: "My scarf is falling on you."   If the other person is wearing your scarf, the Answer above, which says "My scarf fell off you" works, or, if it is happening as you speak, "My scarf is falling off you."   You would not say "My scarf fall....." as "scarf" is singular and takes the singular "falls".
"My scarf falls onto you" is technically OK, but sounds odd, sort of pseudo-literary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say

- My scarf {falls/fell} off on you.

That means that I {am/was} wearing it, then it {falls/fell} **off of me** and **onto you**.

But if you change it to

- My scarf {falls/fell} off you.

It means "You {are/were} wearing my scarf, then it {falls/fell} off of you."
(Where it goes/went, we know not.)